# Uncaught Reference error:InitImgLibView not defined

Tags: javascript

I have a visual webpart solution.A picture library is there whose view i have modified by taking newsletter as a style..
I have written a code in javascript that will allow only image files to get uploaded.
But I am getting the javascript error:Uncaught Reference error:InitImgLibView not defined.

The error is being generated in the thumbnails.aspx dynamic page where i have not written any coding.

Please help

Comment: I'm experiencing this same problem. O365 site, also with an image library list view webpart in the page.